# Belousov–Zhabotinsky Reaction

Tags: equilibrium, kinetics

An experiment in my lab was about the Belousov–Zhabotinsky reaction and we measured 2 times - the induction period, which was the amount of time it took for the solution to change color and back for the first time, and the oscillation period, which was the period of color change cycles after that. The lab manual says to the inverse of both those times as the rate constant K for this reaction, but I am not sure why. Please help?